# the meaning of "this Oscar-tipped production"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Adapted from Uzodinma Iweala’s 2005 Novel about an African boy recruited to a rebel militia, **this Oscar-tipped production** gets a brief UK theatrical outing prior to its high-profile Netflix release on 16 October.*

Source: http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/oct/11/beasts-of-no-nation-review-idris-elba

Can you explain to me what "Oscar-tipped" means in the context of the sentence. Does it mean that the movie was made in the way to gain Oscar, no matter in what category? That would mean that the movie tries to fawn over Oscar Academy's taste which I think is a nonsense. But another explanation does not occur to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tip](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=XRVNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA388&dq=%22so%20did%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeiueyhKPMAhUDOBoKHXA0BYk4ChDoAQg9MAU#v=onepage&q=%22so%20did%20the%22&f=false) verb (INFORMATION) -[T often passive] *mainly UK* - to say that someone is ​likely to be ​successful or ​achieve something:

Oscar-tipped means that people say that it might win an Oscar.